# backbone.js AssociatedModel Error: type must inherit from Backbone.AssociatedModel

Tags: backbone.js

I was looking for a library to follow sub models and came across backbone-associative

I created Model and set the relations. The structure looks like

GatewayModel have relation to GradeModel

GradeModel have relation to ButtonModel

I create obj of GatewayModel and add GradeModel. but when I try to add ButtonModel to GradeModel it throws error

Uncaught Error: type must inherit from Backbone.AssociatedModel

I checked the declaration of all Models and they are correctly extending AssociatedModel

Please could someone help with what the issue could be

I have created JSFiddle here

jsfiddle.net/5d4Fa

[EDIT]
I noticed if i change the type to Backbone.One it works fine. Please could some one explain what is the difference between One and Many.

My understanding is if a Model contains multiple record for relation Model I have to use Backbone.Many but as soon as I use Backbone.Many it start to throw errors

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The issue was related to incorrect type of data passed in collectionType. It expects string and I was passing the value as class

```
type: Backbone.Many,
key: 'grade',
relatedModel: Model,
collectionType: 'Collection'
```